# doctrine DQL query Error: Expected end of string, got '*'

Tags: doctrine, dql

I have DQL query that throws this exception:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException] Error: Expected end of string, got '*'
```

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE Bundle:Table t SET t.column = :variable * 100
```

I don't understand the problem with this query, and those two are working:

```
UPDATE Bundle:Table t SET t.column = 100 * :variable
UPDATE Bundle:Table t SET t.column = 1 * :variable * 100
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is :variable definitely a number (int/float)? If it's a string then it may be that it can't produce a query that's syntactically correct:

UPDATE some table t SET t.column = '1' * 100;

Whereas maybe the versions with a number first "100 * :variable" and "1 * :variable * 100" can cast it correctly because there is an integer first.

Maybe you can post your setParameter() and check if you can call getSQL() to see what the constructed SQL query looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8011 and not fixed until today.

Most likely

```
UPDATE Bundle:Table t SET t.column = ((:variable * 100))
```

will do the trick and have the parser handle the expression correctly. This has been described in https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8011#issuecomment-758492375.

Comment: wow, I can’t remember what I was working on at the time ! still, interesting to know :)